# Changing matrix output text to cyrillic unicode script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, matrix

I am currently using this Matrix script in a project, what I want to do is to convert the character output so that it prints out cyrillic characters rather than chinese characters:

```
      var s = window.screen;
           var width = q.width = s.width;
           var height = q.height = s.height / 6;
           var letters = Array(256).join(1).split('');

           var draw = function () {
             q.getContext('2d').fillStyle='rgba(0,0,0,.05)';
             q.getContext('2d').fillRect(0,0,width,height);
             q.getContext('2d').fillStyle="FF0000";
             letters.map(function(y_pos, index){
               text = String.fromCharCode(3e4+Math.random()*33);
               x_pos = index * 10;
               q.getContext('2d').fillText(text, x_pos, y_pos);
               letters[index] = (y_pos > 768 + Math.random() * 1e4) ? 0 : y_pos + 10;
             });
           };
           setInterval(draw, 33);
```

From what I can gather these two lines of code are responsible for printing the characters out to screen:

```
           var letters = Array(256).join(1).split('');


               text = String.fromCharCode(3e4+Math.random()*33);
```

However this is where I get stuck, it seems it is printing out from a random maths operation. I don't understand the process for changing this and telling it to instead print out the unicode range for the cyrillic script.

Any help would be great, hope I've been clear enough.

EDIT:

I've just been playing about with it and made some sort of progress. The cyrillic alphabet's unicode range runs from '0410' to '042F' - so I edited

```
    text = String.fromCharCode(3e4+Math.random()*33);
```

And rewrote it as
         text = String.fromCharCode(0410, 0411, 0412, 0413, 0414);

This code works but it prints all 5 of the characters at once and ruins the matrix code in the process. What I need to do I think is to get it to print single characters from a defined range this though I feel is currently above my level of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The original is returning a random number between 30000 and 30033.  You can substitute the math to return whichever character codes you like.

"3e4+Math.random()*33" is using an exponent (3e4 converts to 30000) as a base and then getting a random number between 0 and 33 and adding them together to return a character code number between 30000 and 30033.

String.fromCharCode(3e4+Math.random()*33) can be written as

String.fromCharCode(30000 + (Math.random() * 33))

for clarity, but it doesn't need to have the parenthesis around the multiplication.

I'm impressed that String.fromCharCode(0410, 0411, 0412, 0413, 0414) prints all five characters but that's exactly what it's being asked to do.  It also doesn't seem to care if we pass it floating point values and just rounds them off.

Example, if you want it to return all capital letters, you'd want to pass it numbers (or hex values) and have it get one at random.  For capital letters A-Z (65 - 90), it wants one of 26 letters, giving us,

String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.random() * 26)

Returns a number between 65 and 90.  The multiplication has precedence so happens before the addition.

Cyrillic Basic is 1024 to 1279 and 256 characters:

String.fromCharCode(1024 + Math.random() * 256)